# How to manually checkpoint a delta table using PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I have a delta table, and am trying to append data to it and then checkpoint that table. By default I believe it checkpoints every 10 commits, but I would like to override this behaviour and checkpoint manually.

Currenly my code looks like

```py
df = get_some_source_data()
df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(f"{db_name}.{table_name}")
```

I would like to add a line either as part of, or else after the write operation to create a new delta-table checkpoint in the `_delta_log`.

Comment: why do you need this? Checkpoint is just an optimization technique, it's not strictly required

Comment: @Alex Ott, one reason would be to consume that table as a dlt streaming table which cannot be done unless the table has no updates.

Comment: Checkpoint is not related to that - if you write any data to delta, DLT should pickup it even if you don’t have a checkpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `checkpointInterval` table property to `1` (before and after `saveAsTable`).

Otherwise, you'd have to write some code that uses Delta Lake's internal API to trigger checkpointing of the table. I have never done it before though so no idea how viable it is (if at all).